# Decision tree weight base with different criterion

Tags: decision-tree, weighted, rapidminer

How I can do Decision tree weight base with different criteria
(like gain_ratio,information_gain, gini_index, accuracy)
with RapidMiner software?
In Decision tree (weight_base) operator, there is not this option.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use alternate criteria with the weight-based decision tree operator in RapidMiner:

> The Decision Tree (Weight-Based) operator works exactly like the Decision Tree operator with one exception: it uses an arbitrary attribute relevance test criterion instead of the information gain or gain ratio criteria.

If you want to weight your attributes using information gain, I would recommend using the Weight by Information Gain operator instead.  Feel free to re-post on the [RapidMiner community forum](http://community.rapidminer.com) as others may be able to help more.